# Hide woocommerce orders page learn more button

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

When orders page is empty there is a button that is **learn more about orders button **  also another button in coupons button .. we need a way to hide this button is there is a hook or something ?

Button in the page: https://snipboard.io/F2YklM.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you use css?

```
.woocommerce-BlankState-buttons {
    display: none;
}
```

That's how it looks.

[image]

To hide the button on the coupons section you can try this.

```
.woocommerce-BlankState .woocommerce-BlankState-cta {
    display: none;
}
```

That's how it looks for me.

[image]

Comment: Worked great like a charm, but another button is not hidden in the coupons page .. is there is a class to it too ?

Comment: The one in the coupons that is "learn more about coupons did not work unfortunately" can you help ?

Comment: The rules in SO is one question for thread. But you can what I added to my answer.

Comment: Tested it but unfortunately did not work .. can you test it out for the coupons page button too .. we will appreciate it

Comment: Strange, can you try with this? display: none !important;